# Putting a generic lambda into a map

Tags: generics, lambda, kotlin

Ok so the code below is an event system that does the following:

1. Assigns an integer id to a lambda expression
2. Puts the lambda's id in an event's mutable set
3. Maps the integer ID to the lambda expression
4. Returns the id (can be used later to remove events from the lambda)

The code is as follows:

```
class EventHandler {
    companion object {
        val handlers = HashMap<KClass<out Event>, MutableSet<Int>>()
        val idMap = HashMap<Int, (Event) -> Unit>();

        /**
         * @param event     Class of the event you are registering
         * @param handler   What to do when the event is called
         */
        fun <T : Event> register(event: KClass<T>, handler: (T) -> Unit): Int {
            var id: Int = 0;
            while(idMap[id] != null) {
                id++;
            }
            var list = handlers.getOrPut(event, {mutableSetOf()});
            list.add(id);
            idMap[id] = handler;
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

The intended use of this method would be something like this:

```
EventHandler.register(ChatEvent::class) { onChat ->
    println(onChat.message)
}
```

There is an error at the following line: `idMap[id] = handler;`

The error is because the handler is of type `(T) -> Unit`, although it needs to be `(Event) -> Unit` in order to add it to the `idMap`. Although I said that `T` should extend `Event` when I created it, so this shouldn't be a problem. Does anyone know why this happens of if there is a solution?

Comment: Any reason this needs to be a companion object and not its own class?

Comment: @DougStevenson Because I only intend for there to be a single instance of the EventHandler. I tried making it an `object` instead of a `class` and that doesn't fix it (as I expected)

Comment: Kotlin has its own way of doing singletons: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html

Comment: @DougStevenson I tried that as well, which didn't work

Comment: I think what you're asking for here is the same as asking for the method signature `fun foo(x: SuperClass): Unit` to be equivalent to `fun foo(x: SubClass): Unit`. All you've done is taken out the name foo.  From a method signature point of view, they're very much not the same.

Comment: @DougStevenson `T` should be `Event` or a subclass, yes? And being that the lambda would take any `Event` as a parameter, it would take `Event` and any subclass. So shouldn't this work?

Comment: It could take any event as a parameter, but it would only ever be the basic type Event, and not the subclass type. Just like regular methods, the type of the parameters to the lambda must be absolutely known at compile time.  It can't be ambiguous or circumstantial.  So you have to cast it in the lambda in order to get a more specific type if that's what you want.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ah, that makes sense! The lambda that I pass in must take an event, as `(Event) -> Unit` and `(ChatEvent) -> Unit` would be completely separate types.

Comment: @Deanveloper by the way, why do use two maps to store an event handler registration? Isn't one `HashMap<KClass<out Event>, (Event) -> Unit>` enough?

Comment: @Ilya I'd like to add a way to remove the events later, which either means have the front-end user store their runnable (which would look ugly) or return an integer id which they can later use to unregister their listener

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that `idMap` takes a function that receives an `Event` - *any* kind of `Event`.
Then you try to register a function that takes a specified subclass of `Event`, which, when you pull it back out, the compiler won't be able to tell what possible subclass it receives. Yes, you're storing the specific type in your other map, but the compiler can't use that.

I do not believe you can create the mapping system that you want to create. Not without a few more layers of indirection or abstraction...

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get this error is explained well by @jacob-zimmerman in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35975416/869184): `(T) -> Unit` is not a subtype of `(Event) -> Unit` (on the contrary it is a supertype).

You could make an unchecked downcast to required function type:

```
idMap[id] = handler as (Event) -> Unit
```

But then before invoking such handler you must check that an event has type that the handler could accept, for example by querying handler from map based on the type of the event:

```
fun invoke(event: Event) {
    val kclass = event.javaClass.kotlin
    val eventHandlers = handlers[kclass]?.map { idMap[it]!! } ?: return
    eventHandlers.forEach { it.invoke(event) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out an implementation:

```
class Handlers<T: Event> {
    val backingList = ArrayList<(T) -> Unit>()

    fun add(handler: (T) -> Unit) {
        backingList.add(handler)
    }

    fun remove(handler: (T) -> Unit) {
         backingList.remove(handler)
    }

    fun handleEvent(event: T) {
        backingList.forEach { handle ->
            handle(event)
        }
    }
}

class HandlerMap {
     val handlerMap = HashMap<KClass<out Event>, Handlers<out Event>>()

    fun <T : Event> register(event: KClass<T>, handler: (T) -> Unit) {
        val list: Handlers<T>
        if(!handlerMap.containsKey(event)) {
            list = Handlers<T>()
            handlerMap.put(event, list)
        }
        else {
            list = handlerMap.get(event) as Handlers<T>
        }

        list.add(handler)        
    }

    fun <T: Event> getHandlers(event: KClass<T>): Handlers<T> {
        return handlerMap.get(event) as Handlers<T>
    }
}
```

It has to do some casting due to the Map being kind of open, but the system is closed, so the `Handlers` object is guaranteed to be of the exactly right type.
Due to the implementation change, I was pretty sure you didn't care about the index/"id" anymore, but I tried an implementation with it, and it was fine; no real trouble to put it in if you want it.